# What's needed for PHP's mcrypt_decrypt()?

Tags: php, mcrypt

I have a script that uses mcrypt_decrypt() function, but I get the following error

> Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mcrypt_decrypt()

What modules/libraries do I need to include to use this function?  Or is there another reason I'm getting the error?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please see:

- [Mcrypt Requirements](http://de.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.requirements.php)
- [Mcrypt Installation](http://de.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.installation.php)

You need to compile your PHP with `--with-mcrypt[=DIR]` and have libmcrypt Version 2.5.6 or greater on your machine.

Answer (score 16):

sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt

works on ubuntu.

Comment: for the 'simple' amongst us this also requires an apache restart

Comment: as icc97 says, an apache restart is needed, not enough with a reload :)

Answer (score 5):

Configure php5-mcrypt with php5-fpm (Ubuntu 14.04)

I’m going to assume you already have nginx and php-fpm installed and running.

php5-mcrypt should be installed already (it comes bundled with php5-fpm). Just for safety,
apt-get install php5-mcrypt

Create symlink to mods-avaliable,
ln -s /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini

Enable it.
php5enmod mcrypt

Restart php-fpm,
service php5-fpm restart

Restart nginx,
service nginx restart

Done!

Comment: Thanks for this answer, worked perfectly for me where other answers were giving me trouble.

Comment: FINALLY ... someone who knows wtf they are talking about .. only took like 4 stack exchange threads to find this one .. THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 2):

From the [manual](http://us.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.installation.php):

> You need to compile PHP with the
>   --with-mcrypt[=DIR] parameter to enable this extension. DIR is the
>   mcrypt install directory. Make sure
>   you compile libmcrypt with the option
>   --disable-posix-threads.

Generally if PHP says a function is undefined, it means you need to compile in some library.

Answer (score 0):

I above doesn't work, you can try this:

create mcrypt.ini file in /etc/php5/conf.d with content

```
extension=mcrypt.so
```

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded PHP to 5.4 via http://php-osx.liip.ch/ and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

for php 5.3.X

depends on availability of yum mcrypt package , you could use yum packeages

like this :
    yum install php53-mcrypt
and restart httpd

Answer (score 0):

And be carefull about the folder in the phpinfo page : "Scan this dir for additional .ini files" and the next : "Additional .ini files parsed ".

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to php 5.4 running (Works)

```
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
sudo service apache2 restart
```