# Call to undefined function mcrypt_get_iv_size() in PHP 5.3.3 Centos 6

Tags: php, nginx, centos6, mcrypt

I am getting below error in PHP 5.3.3 with Nginx server.

```
Call to undefined function mcrypt_get_iv_size()
```

Os is Centos 6.8 Linux. But I have installed php-mcrypt package.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php - Fatal error: Call to undefined function mcrypt\_get\_iv\_size() in AppServ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27633584/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mcrypt-get-iv-size-in-appserv)

Comment: Yes. But this is nginx server. it seems mcrypt.so not yet loaded. It will not show in phpinfo() page.

Comment: Do you really need PHP 5.3.3? Isn't worth a try with 5.6?

Comment: Lot of applications runs on 5.3.3. If i change, it will be more complected.

Comment: Its more risk...

Comment: Ok. Got it. Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30479231/6361565

Comment: Thanks deChristo. After executing  "service php-fpm restart" it is working fine.